# Is it possible to use VBA code to copy and paste individual ppt slides into a publisher document?

Tags: vba, copy-paste, powerpoint, publisher

I am trying to copy many ppt slides (from the same ppt) onto an existing publisher document. I've been trying to piece a code together to do this but I can't figure it out due to lack of experience.

I preferably want to only copy the shape on each ppt slide and be able to update the publisher document if any changes are made to the ppt. To complicate things is there a way to initially position all the slides in rows and columns when copying them into the publisher document?

This is what I have so far.

```
Sub PPTSlidesToPublisher()
'Copy/Paste Power Point slides Into an existing Publisher document

'Copy Range from PPT
Set rng = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range

Dim appPub As New Publisher.Application

appPub.Open FileName:="filename.pub", _
ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
SaveChanges:=pbPromptToSaveChanges
appPub.ActiveWindow.Visible = True

Dim myDocument As Object
Dim myPage As Object
Dim myShape As Object


'Add a page to the Documenet
Dim shpSlide As Shape
Set rng = OLEObject
Set shpSlide = ActiveDocument.Pages(3).Shapes.AddOLEObject _
(Left:=2, Top:=5, ClassName:="Publisher.Application")

shpSlide.OLEFormat.Activate


End Sub
```